# tshark: only dissect specific packets

Tags: wireshark

Currently I do this to read a network capture file:

```
tshark -r myfile icmp
```

It prints only ICMP packets, which is a protocol on top of IP (not UDP or TCP).

But `myfile` is a large file with lots of HTTP traffic.  I found that `tshark` takes a long time to process this file, and the reason is partly because it processes all the TCP packets fully, even dissecting the HTTP data.  I realized this because it prints error messages related to HTTP dissection.

Since I know the ICMP packets I want are never inside TCP, I tried these:

```
tshark -r myfile 'not tcp and icmp'
tshark -r myfile -2 -R 'not tcp' icmp
```

But tshark still dissects HTTP packets (again I know this because I see HTTP dissector error messages).

I want to save time (and avoid crashes due to dissector bugs) by not dissecting higher-level protocols when a lower-level protocol does not match.

I am aware that I could split my capture files by protocol, but this is not so practical because the exact things I want to look at are not known in advance.

I also tried the `-O` option to enable specific dissectors, but this makes `tshark` print full multi-line details for each packet, which is not what I want.

How can I make `tshark` skip dissecting packets from specific lower-level protocols?

I am using tshark 1.10.6, but I could use newer versions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't correct.  It looks like you are mixing up [Wireshark display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) syntax and [pcap-filter](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) capture filter syntax.

With the latest stable version of [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) (currently 2.4.0), you can specify a display filter to use with the `-Y` option.  For example:

```
tshark -r myfile -Y "icmp"
```

The `-Y` option was available with version 1.10.6 as well.

Alternatively, you could use a *read filter* as follows, but I generally stick to the display filter method above:

```
tshark -r myfile -2R "icmp"
```

Comment: In my question I stated that the `-2R` approach does not work - it still dissects all the packets, even ones which are filtered out (e.g. `not tcp` still ends up dissecting HTTP packets).  And my syntax is not wrong, it is the documentation you may be confused by, because `man tshark` claims the positional arguments are a capture filter, but in fact when reading from a file they are a display filter.

Comment: Maybe the documentation isn't clear, but when reading from a file, the positional argument is a display filter, not a capture filter.  You have a file already; therefore capture filters no longer apply, only read or display filters.  See: https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=tshark.c;h=5c44d64e27ae6fc540ea4d6a8126b738f6d9da5e;hb=HEAD#l1494

In general, I always recommend upgrading to the latest available version, so maybe you want to try that and see if it behaves any differently.  1.10 went EOL over 2 years ago: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LifeCycle

Comment: I know that capture filters don't apply.  I am not using capture filters.  I am using display filters.